# How to restore a memory card to its original state as it's showing double it's size when I try to partition it in fdisk?

Tags: fedora, partition, fdisk, partition-table

I have a 2 GB memory card that I used as install media for Fedora 23 Design Suite. I want to reuse the same memory card for another Linux install media so I tried re-partitioning it with `fdisk`. The first time I tried, the `fdisk` utility has no errors. **So I unplug the memory card, plug it back in again and do an `lsblk` command** but the old partitions used by the Fedora media are still there:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        SIZE  TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
...
sdd         1.9G  disk
|- sdd1     1.8G  part   /run/media/foo/Fedora-Live-Dsgn-x86_64-23-10
|- sdd2       4M  part   /run/media/foo/EFI
|- sdd3    16.2M  part   /run/media/foo/Fedora Live
```

Thinking that the previous `fdisk` operation failed, I unmounted the mounted `/dev/sdd` partitions listed above and did a `dd` command, thinking it would just blank out the disk:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=4M; sync
```

So not I unplug and re-plug the memory card back in and `lsblk` gives me the expected result (no more partitions):

```
$ lsblk
NAME        SIZE  TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
...
sdd         1.9G  disk
```

So now I try to create a new partition table using `fdisk` but I'm surprised that it is reporting the disk to have 3.6 GiB of space!

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdd
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdd: 3.6 GiB, 3881648128 bytes, 7581344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x61f8cba0

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 7579647 7577600  3.6G 83 Linux
```

So my question is how do I restore the memory card to its original state so that it has 1.9GB of disk space and when I do partitions management with `fdisk` it won't report that the memory card is double the size.

I'm using Fedora 23 Gnome (Design Suite spin) so if possible, the commands be specific to this distro.

Comment: I think everything is OK with the USB stick. When you `dd` a .iso to a USB stick, the stick reports the size of the .iso instead of the actual size.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's the bad memory card. Try to check it for bad sectors.

```
badblocks -wvs /dev/sdd
```